Out-File: Performance issue and Script restriction (Powershell)
I have a function called Write-Logs being called in many other scripts/for each loops. and I realize that when it comes to looping it's taking a lot of time. I suppose it's due to I/O overhead. I can’t/am not allowed to update any of the main scripts due to certain reasons. is there something that can be done at the function level to improve the performance? I'm open to any suggestions.
Function Write-Logs {
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$logContent,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$logPath
)

    $currentTime = Get-Date

    If(!(Test-Path $logPath)){
    
        New-Item -Path $logPath -ItemType 'file' -Force
    }

    Write-Output "$($currentTime): $($logContent)" | Out-File $logPath -Append
}

For example my main.ps1
# This test folder could contain more than 1000 items
$mySrc = 'D:\test'
$myLogPath = 'D:\Logs\mylog.txt'

Get-ChildItem -Path $mySrc -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Logs -logContent $_.FullName -logPath $myLogPath

} 



What do you mean by "When it comes to looping"? There aren't any explicit loop statements in the code you've shown

I updated the thread @MathiasR.Jessen. I apologize for the confusion.

The append is causing the issue.  The only way of speeding the code is to open a log file once and then write end of the file.  You code has to open and close the file every time one line is added to the log file.

Thanks @jdweng I suspect the same .. but the challenge mainly I cant touch any main/other scripts.. trying to see if something can be done just at the write-logs level.

You could leave out the test if the logfile exists or not and instead of Write-Output ... just do "$($currentTime): $logContent" | Add-Content -Path $logPath. Add-Content will create the file if it did not exist for you.

Thanks @Theo will try to improve the logic in the function.. but my main concerns are still about performance. Looks like even with Add-Content, performance likely still be the same.

What he meant was Get-ChildItem -Path $mySrc -Recurse | % { "$(Get-Date) $($_.FullName)" } | Add-Content $myLogPath. That can't be slower than what you have right now.

hi @SantiagoSquarzon, as one of my challenges was I couldn't/am not allowed to update anything in my main.ps1 script due to certain reasons

If that's the case then your issue can't be solved. The issue is the I/O overhead but fixing that requires updating the script.

You might consider to create an advanced function with processing blocks using the steppable pipeline:
Write-Log
(Use Singular Nouns)
Function Write-Log {
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeLine=$True)][string]$logContent,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$logPath
    )
    begin {
        $Pipeline = { Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append }.GetSteppablePipeline()
        $Pipeline.Begin($True)
    }
    process {
        $currentTime = Get-Date
        $Pipeline.Process("$($currentTime): $_")
    }
    end {
        $Pipeline.End()
    }
}

Usage:
Get-ChildItem -Path $mySrc -Recurse | Write-Log -LogPath $myLogPath

The performance advantage lays in the fact that you not continuously (re)opening and closing the logfile for every Get-ChildItem FileSystemInfo item but keep it open until the pipeline is ends. See also Performance Considerations / Avoid wrapping cmdlet pipelines

hi @iRon, thanks for sharing this ...my another challenge still remains as I can't update my main.ps1.

I was just reading the comments made to the question. What you could do with the above concept in mind, consider to delay the $Pipeline.End()  with an event, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046047/1701026 and check with every  Process step whether the pipeline has been closed or not. But this is definitely more complicated and adds the danger that the log file not being closed at all.

This problem happens because there are two operations taking place. Write-Output will write the text to the output stream, while Out-File is going to take care of the I/O part of things.
When writing logs, I like using Add-Content. This Cmdlet will write the text directly to the file without outputting it to the stream.
Also, you don't need to check if the file exists, Add-Content will create it automatically. The directory has to exist, though.
Function Write-Logs {
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$logContent,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$logPath
)

    $currentTime = [DateTime]::Now
    try {
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$($currentTime): $($logContent)" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 700
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$($currentTime): $($logContent)"
    }
}

Notice I added a try-catch block. Sometimes the script is so fast the previous write log didn't finish closing the handle to the file yet.

Thank you @FranciscoNabas. The problem for me is performance and how to not touch all other scripts. I guess there may not be much to do in that case
